# Sources to find industrial jobs for mathematicians with a Ph.D., or with advanced backgrounds? (preferably research positions but not necessarily)

Tags: soft-question, mathjobs

Several companies (google, IBM etc.) are known to hire mathematicians with advanced degrees (Ph.D. and so) to work in different sectors; I mean mostly research oriented positions in industry but could be something else too. But I almost never find any such job advertisements in the standard mathjob sites I know of, including mathjobs.org, euro-math-soc.eu/jobs, nordic math jobs etc. Where can I find these type of job advertisements?

Comment: have you tried Linkedin?

Comment: You should also check the company web sites.

Comment: Deane Yang: I'll, but a problem I'm facing is I'm not sure which company is more relevant to my search. Otherwise, I've to go through pile of them and check them all individually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the votes to close. True, this is not a mathematics research question, but neither is the question about where to buy good chalk. Seriously: this is a question that I think many professionals, grad students, etc. would be interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best sources available now is the SIAM site:

http://jobs.siam.org/c/search_results.cfm?vnet=0&site%5Fid=686&str=26

This has quite a mix of jobs at various levels, but you will find research positions there as well.