# transition from academia to industry

Tags: career

**crossposted to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23644/transition-from-academia-to-industry**

I am currently doing a post-doc in pure Math [teaching and research] in the US.
The academic year 2014-2015 will be my last postdoc year and I am currently considering
my next employment possibilities.

For several reasons, I am considering a job outside academia in Europe [I am an E.U. citizen], for my next employment. As I know about nothing else except for my research in Pure Math and teaching of Math, I could use as much advice as possible regarding this potential transition from academia to a non-academia job. I have read through the many related questions and answers. But I still could not find answers to the following questions.

(1) How early in advance do you have to apply for a job outside academia? 
Let me provide a bit more details: I really need employment as soon as my current one ends, b/c I need the money to support my living expenses. So I cannot really afford to spend more than one or two months without employment. I am asking this, b/c for academia jobs one typically applies one year ahead of time, things are standard and clear. But not so clear to me are applications outside academia.

(2) Given that I know nothing about programming right now, what would my chances of getting a programming job be? In other words, would I get some sort of PAID training in programming?

(3) Any sort of comments/advice regarding working for a publishing house?
[such as: salary?]

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is probably more appropriate at academia.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have just added the question there as well. I am hoping to receive answers from mathematicians [holding a PhD in pure Math] who have done a similar transition. So perhaps posting the question on both websites increases my chances of getting such answers.

Comment: Posting the same question on more than one forum usually ticks off readers of both forums, which is unfortunately your intended audience.  Best is to indicate this with a link to the other question on both copies. For the copy here,  something like "crossposted  to academia.se" at the top with a link is suggested.

Comment: Thanks to The Masked Avenger. I have implemented your advice.

Comment: I'm not even sure it will fit the academia subforum (that would be perfectly fine if one tried to move *from* industry to academia asking what rules apply here). The common sense advice is that while, in principle, it can be "too early" to start looking for the possibilities, you cannot lose too much erring on this side (if they cannot wait for you now, they'll just not have that position by the time you are ready anyway), but the opposite error may be fatal. So, I would start probing the ground right away. Even if you don't secure a position, you may establish some useful connections.

Comment: You say you don't know anything outside of Math, but do you know *anyone?* The ideal situation is that you have one (or several) contacts in industry, and they can tell you how thing work (and maybe even pull a few strings for you!).

Comment: In response to the request to close/put the questions on hold:

Comment: my apologies! I am aware tha MO is mostly for research questions. But, after taking a quick look at some questions tagged ``carreer'' and ``soft question'', such as this one:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168381/sources-to-find-industrial-jobs-for-mathematicians-with-a-ph-d-or-with-advance, I had assumed, that, as a matter of fact, my questions would also  be accepted.

Comment: So my reasoning is incorrect. If so, apologies again.

Comment: While I have already posted the question on academia.stackexchange, I was actually hoping that via this forum - MO - I would receive answers from persons in a similar position to mine [holding a PhD in pure Math, with pure Math work experience only]. It seemed to me that pure mathematicians tend to visit MO. I do not know to what extent this is true for academia.stackexchange. And I do not know of other places where the questions would fit, as explained.

Comment: to Mark Grant: Thanks for your insight. I do not have anyone right now in my mind, that works in industry, in a place where I would fit, more or less.